# Is there a way to set Event ID on EventLog sink (in Serilog)?

Tags: serilog

I took a look at [Serilog.Sinks.EventLog](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-eventlog/blob/master/src/Serilog.Sinks.EventLog/Sinks/EventLog/EventLogSink.cs#L101) at Github and noticed there doesn't seem to be a way to set the `Event ID` of the logged event (example IDs [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368560%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Would there exist a way to modify the sink so that it'd be possible? Perhaps with some kind of specially formatted message? I don't know if I should put this here or on Github, I'll try here first. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a mechanism currently for this - designing one seems tricky (but ultimately it'd be a great addition to the project!)

Comment: Indeed, immediately what comes into mind is either a specially formatted message, an interceptor-like sink (a lambda function?) that makes the ultimate call or some kind of an additional object and probably metaprograming. Perhaps one option would be an optional lambda, which would be called with a given sink (e.g. Event Log interface) so that the call is made "on the spot", or so it would look like in code. Just something off top of my head. It looks like the urge in our project can be satisfied by other means, but it'd be a great feature nevertheless!

Comment: I was wondering if a hash of the message template (`"Foo {Bar}"`) could be used to generate a unique (enough) event id? Then producing the right manifest file is the primary consideration... I'm not very familiar with this aspect of the event log however.

Comment: In some situations it would work, but not in all. There are plenty of monitoring tools that read Event Log and one can define rules for occurrence or non-occurrence of specified IDs. This would work if it would be all right to have different IDs, but not easily if someone would like predefine ranges of IDs with some meaning.

Currently Serilog EL sink uses as the ID the  severity level. We can go with that and put the event ID to the message itself and do a "regex" on the message string. It's not ideal, but works, as we are interested on Fatal and Error levels.

Comment: `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` has an `EventId` with an ID and a name. It's up to the logging code (not the provider/sink) to define the event ID. It could be a convention. It could even be the same as for `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`'s `EventId`.